# Mongoose nodejs find not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I'm doing a mongoose find and I've defined collections etc and it all works fine EXCEPT when I try to do a find by a value.

```
var searchID = req.user.id;
      console.log(searchID);


      Locations.find({userid: '541f69e7fd4c3b07108c92c0'}, function(err, location) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(location);
      });
```

the userid is a property which is the ID of the user that created it. The find doesnt work in mongo console either.

Any ideas? I can do finds by the actual _id of the location or any other value.

Comment: How have defined "userid" in your schema. Is it a String or an ObjectId? What does it look like through the mongo shell? `ObjectId("541f69e7fd4c3b07108c92c0")` perhaps?

Comment: Also use `findOne`, instead of `find`, when searching for single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neil Lunn commented, your problem is almost certainly your schema not being correct. Once your mongoose schema clearly defines the `userid` property as being of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`, mongoose will start casting your string value from the query to a proper `ObjectId` instance before sending it to mongodb, and thus the query will start matching documents and you'll see results.

```
{userid: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}}
```